# recursively finding an element in 2d matrix

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, matrix

I'm trying to find a number recursively in a matrix.

```
public class Test2 {
static char arry [][] = {{'#','#','#'},
                         {'#',' ',' '},
                         {'#',' ','#'},
                         {'#',' ','1'},
};

public static void main(String args []){
    recursion(2,1);

}

private static void recursion(int row, int col) {
    if(arry[row][col]=='1' && isInBound(row,col)==true){
        System.out.println("Found at " + row + " " + col);
    }else if ((isInBound(row,col)==true)&& arry[row][col]==' '){
        recursion(row,col+1);
        recursion(row,col-1);
        recursion(row-1,col);
        recursion(row+1,col);

    }

}

private static boolean isInBound(int row, int col) {
    boolean bol = false;
    if(row<= arry.length && col <= arry[0].length){
        bol = true;
    }

    return bol;
}
```

}

I'm trying to make the program in such way that I will be able to start from any positions. for example I'm starting from 2,1 position in this program. I'm getting a out of bounds exception. the code sometimes work for some inputs while using a try catch loop. I don't want to use a try catch unless absolutely necessary. I'm also trying to look for the in all 4 direction in the matrix. That's where my problem begins I'm going out of bound.

Comment: Once you fix this bug, you're going to need to keep track of visited cells somehow, or your search is going to jiggle back and forth between two cells until stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works:

```
public class Test2 {
    static char arry[][] = { { '#', '#', '#' }, { '#', ' ', ' ' },
            { '#', ' ', '#' }, { '#', ' ', '1' }, };
    static boolean[][] visited = new boolean[arry.length][arry[0].length];

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // fill visited array
        for (int i = 0; i < visited.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < visited[0].length; j++) {
                visited[i][j] = false;
            }
        }

        recursion(2, 1);

    }

    private static void recursion(int row, int col) {
        if (!isInBound(row, col) || visited[row][col])
            return;
        visited[row][col] = true;

        if (arry[row][col] == '1') {
            System.out.println("Found at " + row + " " + col);
            return;
        } else if (arry[row][col] == ' ') {
            recursion(row, col + 1);
            recursion(row - 1, col);
            recursion(row + 1, col);
            recursion(row, col - 1);

        }

    }

    private static boolean isInBound(int row, int col) {
        boolean bol = false;
        if (row < arry.length && col < arry[0].length && col >= 0 && row >= 0) {
            bol = true;
        }

        return bol;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just using what you've written so far, you should check if your indexes are valid using `isInBound` first, and immediately `return;` if out of bounds. The way you are currently checking bounds, you will always *use* the bounds before you test them, meaning you're always going to encounter out of bounds exceptions, regardless of where you start.

E.g. at the beginning of `private static void recursion(..)`, add the following:

```
if(!isInBound(row,col)) {
    return;
}
```

And no subsequent array bound test is necessary. Thus, any recursive call against an invalid bounds by your recursive calls will simply return without incurring an out of bounds exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void recursion(int row, int col) {
    if(arry[row][col]=='1'){
        System.out.println("Found at " + row + " " + col);
    }
    else if (arry[row][col]=='#'){
        return;
    }
    if (isInBound(row,col + 1)){
        recursion(row,col+1);
    }
    if(isInBound(row, col - 1)){
        recursion(row, col - 1)
    }
    if(isInBound(row -1, col)){
        recursion(row-1,col);
    } 
    if(isInBound(row + 1, col) {
        recursion(row+1,col);
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Assuming you're skipping #'s when you find one.